# Specifying cells in excel using TCOM

Tags: excel, tcl

The command $cells Item 2 A {SomeText} doesn't set the text in the cell A2 instead it assigns the text in the cell A1. Any idea on why its behaving like this???

```
              set application [::tcom::ref createobject "Excel.Application"]
              set XlFileFormat(xlCSV) [expr 6]
              set workbooks [$application Workbooks]
              set workbook [$workbooks Add]
              $application DisplayAlerts False
              set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
              set worksheet [$worksheets Item [expr 1]]
              set cells [$worksheet Cells]
            $cells Item 2 A {Range}


              $workbook SaveAs {c:\test.csv} $XlFileFormat(xlCSV)      
              $application Quit
```

Comment: What does it do when you use different numbers, e.g. "4 A"?

Comment: It just places everything in the A1 cell.. It is because of the CSV format i guess...Not pretty sure why this is behaving strangely...

Comment: In this example, I fail to see how the file is saved.  Line 2 just sets a member of an array to an integer 6, that's all.  On the other hand, you add a workbook then add a sheet and then modify it.  I have a vague feeling that Excel may be saving something else when you tell it to save what you populated as CSV is just a matrix, it does not know anything about worksheets and workbooks.

Comment: edited the question.. This is how i save it...

Comment: I'm positive this is because of CSV format.. when try to do the same and write the data in .xls format, evrything seems to be working fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's an explanation: when saving to CSV, Excel seems to save just the data which form the "bounding box" inside the (virtualized) sheet grid.  In other words, you have not modified any data in the cells of the first row, and hence it's not saved.

This simple program (JScript for WSH):

```
var app = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var wbs = app.Workbooks;
var wb  = wbs.Add;
var wss = wb.Worksheets;
var ws  = wss.Item(1);
var cells = ws.Cells;

app.DisplayAlerts = false;

cells.Item(2, "B") = "B2";
cells.Item(2, "C") = "C2";
cells.Item(3, "B") = "B3";
cells.Item(3, "C") = "C3";

wb.SaveAs("foo.csv", 6);
app.Quit();
```

which sets four cells arranged in a rectangular block offset by one column and one row from the top-left corner of the sheet, produces this CSV file:

```
B2,C2
B3,C3
```