# Creating tabs in CSV using TCOM

Tags: excel, csv, tcl

I want to add tabs to the .csv file I'm creating using the TCOM package in TCL. The following is the code I used to create a second tab. But I don't see a second Tab.  I just see the first tab created.

```
set application [::tcom::ref createobject "Excel.Application"]
set XlFileFormat(xlCSV) [expr 6]
set workbooks [$application Workbooks]
set workbook [$workbooks Add]                         
$application DisplayAlerts False
set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]

set worksheet1 [$worksheets Item [expr 1]] 
set cells_worksheet1 [$worksheet1 Cells]

set worksheet2 [$worksheets Item [expr 2] 
set cells_worksheet2 [$worksheet2 Cells]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you call a "tab" here, is really a worksheet — a concept only existing in certain office spreadsheet applications such as Excel, you're using.  When saving/loading data in their *native* file formats, those applications are able to preserve this high-level structure, but [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is way simpler: it's just a two-dimensional matrix.  Due to this simplicity, the CSV format can be used only to store the contents of a single sheet of a workspace maintained in a typical office spreadsheet software.  Moreover, CSV won't store advanced stuff such as cell references or formulas or cell formatting etc — only raw data.

Now please evaluate carefully the following pieces of advice:

- You should get under you skin the idea that in your case — scripting Excel via COM from Tcl, — Tcl and COM are conceptually just thin dumb layers which do nothing of interest: all the heavy lifting is done by Excel.  This means, that if you face a problem with scripting some Excel action, *think of Excel,* not these wrappers. Performing the following steps should usually help:

  1. Fire up Excel and try to carry out your intended actions *manually.*  In your particular case, this would have saved your from asking this question as you'd see you just can't save a multi-sheet document to a CSV-formatted file.
  2. Record a macro, then open up the macro editor and see what Excel scripted for you (in VBA).  The translation of this code to COM-mediated calls from whatever runtime is pretty straightforward.  This is a common approach to scripting such software using COM.
- Read the docs!  There's no excuse for not reading an introductory material on what CSV is since the docs are in abundance.  [You have already been told](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10040289/720999) that CSV is way simpler you think it is; this should have rung some bell.
- Consider reading through the http://whathaveyoutried.com — it appears you did not perform much research before asking.